# How to exclude primary key selection from the query when using CDbCriteria on YII

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, yii

I faced a problem with the default selection of primary key when using CDbCriteria joined with another table.
I have 2 tables:

```
Content (
  id int2 pk,
  title varchar,
  content varchar,
  categoryid int2 fk
)
Category (
  id int2 pk,
  name varchar,
  ...
)
```

I want to select `name` and `count(id)` in category (**nothing else**) and group them by name to get the quantity of the category. But when I try the following I get an error because of the primary key selection.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with=array('category' => array('alias' => 'c', 'select' => 'c.name, COUNT(c.id) AS quantity'));
$criteria->select=array();
$criteria->group='c.name';
$result=Content::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

It gives me the following error:
`[Err] ERROR:  column "t.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`
The solution of the problem I am thinking of now is getting the generated SQL from the criteria and replace it to empty string (I couldn't find the way to get the SQL yet) or change the framework code (which seems much more complicated).
My db manager is PostgreSQL.
P.S. adding ids to grouping didn't help the quantity everywhere becomes 1.
**Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I think group must be in this:

```
$criteria->with=array('category' => array('alias' => 'c', 'select' => 'c.name, COUNT(c.id) AS quantity', 'group' => 'c.name'));
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where the grouping is, when you select the id no sense to group.